# Need help in pressing "enter or new line" to allow user to return to main menu

Tags: c++

I have a school assignment almost done. I need a small help in fixing a part i couldn't solve. Much help will be appreciated.

I want to allow user to press enter to return to main menu. However, i am unable to do so, may someone advise me. I wish to make it such that no matter how many/what characters the user inputs, as long as he ends with a enter, it will return to main menu.

I have already done the assignment, below is a snippet of the problem i'm facing.

```
//switch statement on top

    string enter = " ";

     case 2:
        Menu2(id, gridxHighest, gridxLowest, gridyHighest, gridyLowest);
        cout << "Press <enter> to go back to main menu ...";
        getline(cin, enter);
        cin >> enter;
        cout << endl;
        break;
```

My actual result i get is that when i press enter, a new blank line will just appear.

Comment: You are reading from `std::cin` twice: `getline(cin, enter); cin >> enter;` so you'd need to press enter twice.

Comment: ... and please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And also: `string enter= " ";`is a `space`, not an empty string. --> `string enter="";`

Answer (score 0):

Remove your

```
getline(cin, enter);
cin >> enter;
```

replace it with

```
cin.ignore();
```